# Vim - Close Ruby method

Tags: vim

```
def some_func(arg)
    puts arg
```

Lets say I have the above simple code. I just finished typing 'puts arg'.  Now I want to press enter and type in 'end'.  The problem is that when I press enter Vim sets my indentation to the same level as 'puts arg'.  I then have to back out the indentation for that line to match that of 'def'.  There has got to be an easier way, but I Google'd and couldn't find a simple answer.  I would love to stay in Vim edit mode and skip jumping into visual mode.

Comment: You could use command mode of vim and type `:set noautoindent` or enter the line in your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: It's a good idea.  The one thing is that I do like autoindent.  I just want to be able to override it at the end of a code block.

Comment: Adding `filetype plugin indent on` to your `vimrc` should give you the desired behavior.

Comment: more specifically, typing `end` should remove the undesired indent.

Comment: Thanks all.  It wasn't Vim, it was me:)  All I had to do was ignore indentation, type 'end', press return, and indentation for that line would self-correct.

Comment: Well, think that vim has no way of knowing that you are done with the method...